# Get-Acl from Different Domains

Tags: powershell

Auditors are asking questions about ACL on certain groups in a couple of different domains.  I have put together a script that returns the information I need for our primary domain (Accounts) but can't seem to get it to switch to another domain (Medco) to get the ACL for those groups.  How do I switch the `Get-Acl` cmdlet to read the information from that other domain?

```
Get-Content 'U:\ad\scripts\Scripts - Input\ADGroup Permissions - Medco.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  $OutputG = $_
  $Group = "AD:" + (Get-ADgroup $_ -Server Medco).distinguishedname
  (Get-Acl $Group).access |
    Where-Object {
      $_.ActiveDirectoryRights -like "*write*" -or
      $_.ActiveDirectoryRights -like "*delete*"
    } |
    Sort-Object IdentityReference |
    Select-Object identityreference,
      @{L='Access'; E={$_.ActiveDirectoryRights -join ";"}},
      @{"n"="Group";"e"={"$OutputG"}}
} | Export-csv ".\Scripts - Output\ACL_Medco_$CurrentDate.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The scenario is I'm reading group names from a .txt file for specific domains and then a `ForEach-Object` to pass the group name to get the `distinguishedName` to use it in the `Get-Acl`.  The first set of groups for the primary domain returns the information correctly (not showing that part).  I know the groups exist in the next domain but the problem is that the `Get-Acl` for it throws an error saying

```
Get-Acl : Cannot find path 'AD:CN=Medco Infrastructure & Security,OU=Recipients -
Distribution Lists,OU=Legacy Exchange 5.5,OU=Exchange,DC=medco,DC=com' because it
does not exist.
At line:4 char:4
+   (Get-Acl $Group).access
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use New-PSDrive to create new AD query provider, instead of default one AD:. Then you will query that new drive and not default one.
For example:

```
New-PSDrive -Name AD2 -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Server 'DC.medco.com' -root "//RootDSE/"

$Group = 'AD2:' + (Get-ADgroup $_ -Server Medco).distinguishedname
(Get-Acl $Group).access |
. . .
```

In case you want to dynamically assign server, you can use something like

```
(Get-ADDomainController -DomainName 'medco.com' -Discover).hostName
```

and if needed, domain name you can get from existing distinguishedname

If you have more than two domains, then you should use Remove-PSDrive before setting new one with the same name. Best would be to group AD groups per domain to minimize adding/removing commands.

Answer (score 1):

This can help, but be sure to include the **-Identity** and the **-Server** parameters as well to ensure you get the right results. I did this for Get-ADComputer, but it can also work for Get-ADObject:

```
New-PSDrive -Name AD2 -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Server 'my.other.subnet.net' -root "//RootDSE/"    
$Group = 'AD:' + (Get-ADComputer -Identity 'FakeComputer-01' -Server 'my.other.subnet.net').distinguishedname    
(Get-Acl $Group).access
```

Sometimes not including the other parameters will still return an error.